# Method parameter: destructuring + keeping original parameter (ReactJS component)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, destructuring

is there any way to achieve method parameter destructuring, but also be able to get method parameter.

In the context of a React application with stateless components, I'd like to be able to replace

```
const MyComponent = (props) => {
  const {prop1, prop2} = props;
  return (
    <div className={prop1 + '-' + prop2}>
      <Child {...props}/>
    </div>
  ) 
}
```

with a more concise syntax like

```
const MyComponent = (props: {prop1, prop2}) (
  <div className={prop1 + '-' + prop2}>
    <Child {...props}/>
  </div>
)
```

Is there any syntax like that available?

Comment: such a syntax doesn't exist, to my knowledge

Answer (score 2):

we have this:

```
const MyComponent = ({ prop1, prop2, ...rest }) (
  <div className={prop1 + '-' + prop2}>
    <Child prop1={prop1} prop2={prop2} {...rest} />
  </div>
)
```

Comment: @free-soul, thanks for editing, but it's not really more concise than the initial implementation, and become less concise if I destructure more parameters

Comment: that's right, I concur.

Answer (score 2):

If you define your component as `function`, you can use `arguments` object:

```
function MyComponent({ prop1, prop2 }) (
  <div className={prop1 + '-' + prop2}>
    <Child {...arguments[0]}/>
  </div>
)
```

Comment: That's a nice idea, but isn't there something more idiomatic we can do?